# Sending HTML via ajax - adds a backsklash in a tag

Tags: php, wordpress, email

the following problem. I get a textblock with placeholder tags, replace these placeholders with the correct content and place this textblock in a textarea. jquery val().

In this textarea everything is displayed correctly. line breaks and also a URL link. (the HTML of the a tag)

If I now get this val() and send it via Ajax to a PHP function which sends a mail, the problem occurs. The textblock is the textbody of the mail.

The text block is displayed correctly in the mail, Bold tags, line breaks, no problem.

But with the a tag I get backslashes in.

I have now looked a lot, with escaping, json, etc but it will not succeed.

Probably I have lost my way. Can someone tell me where it is and point me in the right direction.

Here are a few code excerpts.

```
$( ".jsClickClaimsSendSH" ).click(function() {
    var ajaxurl = $(this).data("ajax");
    var action = 'claim_defects_breach_of_contract_send_mail';
    
    var claimtype = $(this).data("claimtype");
    var leadID = $(this).data("leadid");
    var uniqueid = $(this).data("uniqueid");
    
    var subject = $("#claimsmailbodycontainer .claimssubjectbody").val();
    var mailbody = $("#claimsmailbodycontainer .claimsmailbody").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
    
        data: {
            action : action,
            claimtype : claimtype,
            leadID : leadID,
            uniqueid : uniqueid,
            subject : subject,
            mailbody : mailbody
        },
        success: function( result ){
        }
    });         
    
    
});
```

In the PHP function it looks like this

```
$mailbody = $_POST['mailbody'];


$headers = [];
$headers[] = 'From: '.$mailFrom;
$headers[] = 'Reply-To: '.$mailReplyTo;        
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
$headers[] = 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 

ob_start();
include_mail_template_php ($getPageLanguage.'/claimmail');
$message = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); 

// '%%text-body%%' is placeholder tag in the mail template for the $mailbody
$variables = array(
    '%%text-body%%',
); 

// set replacements for variables
$values = array(
    $mailbody
);

$message = str_replace( $variables, $values, $message );


wp_mail($empfaenger, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The HTML of the a tag in the mail looks like this. You cant click on that link.

```
   <a+href="http://localhost/abc/page/?l=6194a9edac24c"+target="_blank">more</a>
```

**additions1**

In the request from the jquery call, the HTML still looks good.

```
  <a+href="http://localhost/abc/page/?l=6194a9edac24c"+target="_blank">hier</a>
```

The part of the mail template where a placeholder tag is located. This placeholder will be replaced with the mail body text.

```
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td style="padding: 20px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; background-color: white; white-space: pre-line; ">
        <p style="margin: 0;">
            %%text-body%%
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**additions2**

Where does the a day come from.
I have saved a text with ACF and the placeholder is like this

```
  <a href="%%LinkInvoice%%" target="_blank">more</a>
```

Comment: @HowardE the problem is about the content of the mail that gets send on the server side, so whether or not that AJAX request actually does something with any response, shouldn't be relevant here.

Comment: @cbroe misread. Whoops

Comment: Can you please clarify, what data you are actually sending, and what your mail template looks like? Because it is not the actual attribute value delimiters getting escaped - you are apparently using double quotes for those. But then inside, there is another set of single quotes around the values.

Comment: @CBroe I added some code and informatiosn. i hope this what you looking for.

Comment: Still unclear to me which data you are passing from where to where now. What is the actual content of your textearea on the client side? It is weird that spaces have apparently been converted to `+` characters, as if there was URL encoding applied at some point, or something like that.

Comment: And how many "levels" of placeholder replacement are we actually talking about here? Your PHP code contained only `%%text-body%%`, but now apparently there's `%%LinkInvoice%%` directly in the ACF field content as well, where does _that_ get substituted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`wp_unslash()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unslash/) function.

Usage in this case would be something like:

```php
$message = str_replace( $variables, $values, $message );
$message = wp_unslash( $message ); // Strip slashes here!


wp_mail($empfaenger, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Or maybe even...

```php
// set replacements for variables
$values = array(
    wp_unslash( $mailbody )
);
```

Your question doesn't give enough information to where the example `<a>` tag output is coming from.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that tomorrow. Unfortunately, I'm already out of the office.

Where does the a day come from.
I have saved a text with ACF and the placeholder is like this

     <a href="%%LinkInvoice%%" target="_blank">more</a>

In the whole textblock are still eiinieg other placeholders.
I get the text, replace all placeholders, and then put it in a textarea. Since if necessary still adjustments must be made to the text. This text is sent with the Ajax call to the PHP function, the mail is assembled and the mail is sent.